# Where to save the password for email in Android app (using JavaMail API)?

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, jakarta-mail

I'm creating an android app which has an option for client to send email using JavaMail API.

I am using my email address to do this. I just want to make sure that where should I save my password. Is it safe to save it in the resources? If not, can you please suggest any method to do so?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Save in sharedperference

Comment: encrypt and save in sharedpref or db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, keeping passwords in resources is not good idea, because anyone can very easily read it (using i.e. apktool). 
Keeping it in code isn't also safety, beacuse apk can be easily decompile and (even if code is obfustated) it can be found.
Sending it from the server site can be also dangerous, 
because it could be sniffed (even if https would be used).

In sum it isn't good idea to use your email address. 
Why every user can not use their own email? In this situation you can save user passwords (for future use) in shared preferences (like Shane said).

Comment: Thank you for your help. As, the user might not find it safe using their email credential so I am not using their email. Is there any other way that the user can mail me without opening the email client.

Comment: Have the client connect to a web service you control, and have the web service accept the messages details, compose the message, and use JavaMail to send the message to you.